# In mysql Multi-Source replication,replicate-rewrite-db is not working

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

In mysql,
i have Configured Two master to single slave.
i want to replicate from different db to single db.
so i mentioned replicate-rewrite-db=TEST->TEST1
I INSERTED IN TABLE test in  ONE OF THE MASTER WITH DB NAME TEST.
slave has TEST1 DB and test table.
replication is not happenning.
i think this is due to Multi-source replication..i mean we can;t do it with multiple master configured to single slave?
any one idea how to achieve replicate-rewrite-db=TEST->TEST1 in multi-source replication

Answer (score 0):

when use multi source replication, you should write your config as:

```
[mysqld]
master_usa.replicate-rewrite-db=customer->customer_usa
master_emea.replicate-rewrite-db=customer->customer_emea
```

here `master_usa` and `master_emea` are channel name.

the example above is introduced by **Claudio Nanni** in [mariadb blog](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/multisource-replication-how-resolve-schema-name-conflicts)